# Where filename like '%_123456_%'

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to query a table with a like statement. Is `_` considered a wildcard symbol in postgres? Would

```
select * from table where field1 like '%_123_%'
```

return the same thing as

```
select * from table where field1 like '%123%'
```

Comment: Yes. `_` is a wildcard in (standard) SQL

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example from the official documentation regarding wildcards in Postgres:

```
'abc' LIKE 'abc'    true
'abc' LIKE 'a%'     true
'abc' LIKE '_b_'    true
'abc' LIKE 'c'      false
```

_ is a wildcard for one character, while % is a wildcard for multiple characters.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `_` is a wildcard symbol that matches one character. It can't be an empty match, so no, those statements are not the same. The first requires the string be at least 5 characters long while the second only requires 3 characters.

If you're familiar with regexes, `%123%` is equivalent to `.*123.*`, while `%_123_%` is equivalent to `.+123.+`.

From the [PostgreSQL manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-matching.html):

> To match a literal underscore or percent sign without matching other characters, the respective character in *pattern* must be preceded by the escape character. The default escape character is the backslash but a different one can be selected by using the `ESCAPE` clause. To match the escape character itself, write two escape characters.

Comment: what if I want it to actually match the string _? My field values are

Comment: report 123456_11111111_33333333.pdf

Comment: I'm trying to find that 123456_ match

Answer (score 1):

yes

_ matches one char while % matches lots of chars.